# Kafka (MSK) and MirrorMaker2 disaster recovery procedures for producers and consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have two questions I'm hoping someone with experience in MSK/Kafka and MirrorMaker2 can help with.

Currently we have a production MSK 2.7.0 cluster with 3 brokers and roughly 1T in topic data. We use the Debezium plugin for most things, a few jdbc/mysql sink connectors and then a handful of random consumers so far. For DR purposes, I'm considering adding a second MSK cluster of the same size and using MirrorMaker2 to replicate everything to it. I've done a fair amount of searching and reading about how others might be approaching DR for Kafka. It seems that MM2 is the standard.

1. I've seen conflicting views on whether active/standby or active/active is recommended. It seems that active/active would be ideal but it comes with a lot of considerations for producers and consumers, mostly when event ordering is important. Curious if anyone can elaborate on that, and how realistic it would be in setting up that topology. Event order is important for most of our cases.
2. For an active/standby configuration, it's not clear to me after what I've read what to plan for in the event the primary cluster goes down permanently and all of the consumers/producers have to migrate over to the new cluster. There's a lot written about how MM2 replicates its own offset data, but I'm not finding much about what a consumer needs to account for when being moved over to the replicated topic. I'm especially interested in what it would mean to move the Debezium connectors over, and if it has a mechanism built in for such a thing or what I should expect.

Comment: 2) No, Kafka Connect (like clients) don't "failover". You'd need to remap all relevant DNS entries for `bootstrap.servers` in the event of the "primary" going down. Otherwise, you have to go over all config files and change them all. However, this also assumes the new cluster has all relevant topics/offsets/ACLs/credentials, etc of the original cluster. 1) I don't think MirrorMaker2 re-orders anything unless partition counts differ between the cluster's topics

Comment: @OneCricketeer 2) I understand that I would need to account for the new bootstrap servers in the event the primary cluster fails. What I'm not clear on is if I would need to account for the consumer's/producer's offsets. How does the consumer know where to pick up from? 1) I suppose if you had a consumer on both the primary and secondary topic, you would just have to account for double writes, unless there was communication between the two consumers so that they don't process the same events, at which time I would imagine ordering might come into play.

Comment: I haven't used MM2, but did use MM1, and what we did was deploy "regional consumers". So, `topic` was local to a region (say us-east), but could be mirrored into a remote "us-west"cluster as `topic.us-east`. Then, it's up to consumers to decide whether to process all mirrored topics using regex pattern, or only the local ones. Then we had a policy that there could be no loops, meaning consuming from a "remote, mirrored" topic shouldn't end up being mirrored back to the source, had tobe a local-region topic... It worked well, then we trusted that 5+ brokers would never crash at once in a region

Comment: The case we want to account for would be something like a network partition or some other reason an entire cluster would go down in a region, however unlikely. Based on my research so far, this must be an incredibly rare case because it's hardly mentioned and if it is, only as a hypothetical.

Comment: Kafka itself doesn't have any cross-cluster failover mechanism, so yes, active/active isn't really (easily) possible. Even in active/passive, in the event a region/cluster fails, and offsets had been migrated up-to that point to the passive, then there isn't really a way to migrate them back to the active, in the opposite direction, AFAIK, once the cluster comes back. You'd need to manually seek the offsets forward, however producers had been sending data to the passive the whole time the active is down, so those offsets may not even exist to be seeked to...